# CSS3 Transitions with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

I have the `-webkit-transition-duration` property set on a div, whose height is set by another class. When I use jQuery to toggle the class, it the transition does something funky.

It goes all the way up, and then is set to the proper height instead of just moving from `50px` height to automatic height which is what I expect it to do. What's the fix for this?

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XcFxQ/1/

Comment: Very wierd... Animating through jQuery only doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/XcFxQ/2/

Although the height is not strictly auto. It manually sets the height in order to make it animate.

Comment: No explanation provided :(

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work correctly without -webkit-transition-property and instead using jQuery 1.7 with jQuery UI as in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjFAt/

In my testing, this produced the cleanest, most robust results.

Now, I'm not sure if you're keen on including jQuery UI in your webpage. If not, it's my best guess that you might have to work around the rendering flaws using some more Javascript (ie. if hasClass, then animate, etc...)

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer not to include jQuery UI, but I could probably work around it with jQuery's animate.  I was hoping that there was a way to do this with CSS itself, but I guess not.  Thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers. I was stuck in my project as I had make a side bar menu in bootstrap. I had to toggle class between col classes. Jquery itself does not allow any transitions. Therefore used jquery UI to accomplish this task and it worked lke a charm