# Better way to show/hide series of textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a variable to keep track of the textbox that will be appearing when a user clicks on a checkbox. There is a series of 4 checkboxes and regardless of which one the user clicks on first, a checkbox will appear. The solution I am providing here works and is doing exactly as I want it to, but I'm wondering if there is a better way I can do this using jQuery.

```
<input name="purposeOfFees" type="checkbox" value="New" class="radio expendable1" />Expendable materials1
<br />
<input name="purposeOfFees" type="checkbox" value="New" class="radio expendable2" />Expendable materials2
<br />
<input name="purposeOfFees" type="checkbox" value="New" class="radio expendable3" />Expendable materials3
<br />
<input name="purposeOfFees" type="checkbox" value="New" class="radio expendable4" />Expendable materials4
<br />
<br />
<p class="text purposeOfFeesText">For each check box above give a detailed description of the expenditures.</p>
<p>
    <textarea rows="" cols="" class="textarea expendable1 purposeOfFeesText" name="RITextArea"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <textarea rows="" cols="" class="textarea expendable2 purposeOfFeesText" name="RITextArea"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <textarea rows="" cols="" class="textarea expendable3 purposeOfFeesText" name="RITextArea"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <textarea rows="" cols="" class="textarea expendable4 purposeOfFeesText" name="RITextArea"></textarea>
</p>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
var textboxCounter = 0;
$('.purposeOfFeesText').hide();

$('.radio.expendable1, .radio.expendable2, .radio.expendable3, .radio.expendable4').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        textboxCounter += 1;
        $('.textarea.expendable' + textboxCounter).show(500);
        if (textboxCounter == 1) { $('.text.purposeOfFeesText').show();
                                 } 
    } else {
        $('.textarea.expendable' + textboxCounter).hide();
        $('.textarea.expendable' + textboxCounter).prop('value', '');
        textboxCounter -= 1;
        if (textboxCounter < 1) { $('.text.purposeOfFeesText').hide();
                                }
    }
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7ydk/

Like I said, this solution is working for me as I want it to, but I'm wondering if there are any functions or another way I could've organized this that would've been more effective or more aligned to good programming practices. Any suggestions are welcome and thanks for checking this out.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that it comes to my mind is using a $().toggleClass() jQuery function, and style the thexboxes with a styles definition, as it is faster then seting .show(), .hide().

--- It depends of the design .. but you could use a similar aproach

```
<div>
 <input type='checkbox'.... />
 <textarea  style="display:none"/>
</div>

<script>
$('input').on('click',function(){
  $(this).is(':checked'){
    $(this).parent().find('textbox').css({opacity:0}).show().animate({opacity:1},500);
  }else{
    $(this).parent().find('textbox').animate({opacity:0},500,function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I originally had it adding a .hide attribute that manipulated the textareas, but I wanted to add a small fade to it so I went with the .show/.hide instead. Can you do this type of animation with .toggleClass()??

Comment: Yes, you can! Toggle a `.fade-hidden` class which applies `opacity: 0`, then place `transition: opacity 2s` (or however long you want it to take) on the main element class.

Comment: if you are developing only for new browsers the you can use a transition: opacity 1s; or something like this, but if you are supporting older browsers you need to use a jQuery animation.
.animate()
.fadeTo()
or
fadeIn()

Comment: Good point. Although it will hide the element content, it [won't show the animation in IE9 and earlier](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions). Also keep in mind that opacity !== display:none, and the element will still take up the same dimensions on the page (you just won't be able to see it).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to build upon @ErikS's answer.

When it comes to using animations using CSS class and toggleClass method, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205189/css3-transitions-with-toggleclass). It will probably be a good starting point.

Other parts might also need to be changed.

It seems to me that there is no good reason not to select all checkboxes using their common class name.

```
$('.radio').click(function() {})
```

You might also consider using method .on() instead of click(). This is a very small optimization, but I think it's at least worth mentioning.

Second of all, you keep creating new jQuery objects to fetch targeted textarea, which is obsolete because you can cache the first call.

```
var target = $('.textarea.expendable' + textboxCounter)
```

Thirdly, method calls can be chained. This might not be an optimization, but looks cleaner.

```
target.hide().prop('value', '');
```

To continue cleaning the code and to use the proposal by ErikS, instead of counting how many textareas have been displayed, just use toggleClass, it will handle everything for you.

And the last thing I want to mention is that you might want to use a better way of determining which textarea will get displayed. You could utilize data attribute or use jQuery's index() method to find out index of checkbox acted upon, because it has the same index as its textare.

To conclude this, here is my proposal for your code. It might not be the best code in the world, but it looks cleaner to me.

```
$('.purposeOfFeesText').addClass('display');

var checkboxes = $('.expendable');

checkboxes.click(function () {
    var that = $(this),
        index = checkboxes.index(that),
        target = $('textarea').eq(index);
    target.toggleClass('display');
});
```